# Powershell Copy-Item going up few directories

Tags: powershell

I am trying to provide a path to Copy-Item cmdlet in Powershell which goes up few directories but I am getting error

> "ERROR -  failed with error: "A positional parameter cannot be found
>   that accepts argument '......\'."

The command I am trying to execute is

```
Copy-Item $Source + "..\..\..\" + ($environment) + "\*.config" $destination
```

Can anyone please guide me how can I go up few directories while providing a path to Copy-Item

Answer (score 3):

You need to parenthese the first argument (source):

```
Copy-Item ($Source + "..\..\..\" + ($environment) + "\*.config") $destination
```

Consider using the [Join-Path](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113347) cmdlet when combining a path. You could also write something like:

```
$sourceDir = Join-Path (Get-Item $Source).Parent.Parent.Parent $environment
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir -Filter '*.config' | Copy-Item -Destination $destination
```

Comment: I would try to avoid using string concatenation to build a path. however, if your solution is working, you don't have to change it.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to put double quotes around the whole path rather than concatenating.

```
Copy-Item "$Source\..\..\..\$environment\*.config" $destination
```